# why is console.log(XHR.responceText) logging undefined in javascript

Tags: javascript, console, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

Here is my code:
[My Javascript Code][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP9Vk.png

and the result is just undefined:
[undefined printed in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5UH5.png)

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a typo in `responceText`.
It should be `responseText`